# Can I read excel file column by column in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, text

can I read excel file column by column? I would like to read xlsx file first column and when I get to an empty cell I will load another column.I've tried what's in the code but it's probably complete nonsense.
There are three bugs in my code: **Error    CS0161  'Class1.ReadCell(int, int)': not all code paths return a value**

Perhaps an explanation is enough.

I tried this:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile();
        }

        public void OpenFile()
        {
            Class1 excel = new Class1(textBox1.Text,1) ;
            string path = textBox1.Text+".txt";
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);

           tw.Write(excel.ReadCell(0, 0));
           tw.Close();
        }

        
    }
    }
```

Class1:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using _Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    class Class1
    {
        string path = "";
        _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb;
        Worksheet ws;
        private object excelWorksheet;

        public Class1(string path, int Sheet)
        {
            this.path = path;
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
        }
        public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
        {
            for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for ( j = 1; j < 100; j++)
                {
                    int first = 65 + i;
                    string coordinates = ((char)first).ToString() + j;

                    if (ws.Range[coordinates].Value == "Z_KomSilnice_L (24200)/7 ")
                    {
                        return ws.Range[coordinates].Value;
                    }
                    else
                        return "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your two `return[i, j];` probably need to be `return ws.Cells[i,j]` like your third example.

Comment: However you can't just return cells: if you want strings you'll need to return the Value as you're computing on your cellValue line. There's also .ValueType (I think) which is probably the best way of checking if a cell is empty or not.

Comment: Interop is not a good choice if you purely want to work with files - it's awkward, sometimes unreliable and also requires the machine running the code to have the relevant Excel dependencies installed. Instead there are plenty of (free) libraries which can interact with the file format directly, without relying on Excel application components. e.g. ClosedXML, NPOI and others. Your task would probably be simpler using those libraries instead.

Comment: @Rup may I ask how can I achieve this?

Comment: @ADyson 
any advice for a complete beginner?

Comment: I've already given my advice - don't use interop! Use a different library. They will have slightly different syntax for accessing the cells anyway, and therefore you won't run into the exact specific error you've got here...so there's no point in me advising you on that. These libraries all have tutorials, documentation, tags on stackoverflow etc that you can use to learn how to do specific tasks within them. Just pick one you like the look of, and install it via Nuget.